# Finding an array of numbers knowing the distribution and possible values

Tags: combinatorics

There is an array of 16 unknown numbers, which I need to find. I know that numbers are whole and can take values from 0 to 7.

I also know what values the numbers can take in the array. I will give an example array in this question to make things more clear.
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 23 \\ 14 \\ 05 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 06 \\ 15 \\ 24 \\ 33 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 71 \\ 62 \\ 53 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 54 \\ 63 \\ 72 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 07 \\ 16 \\ 25 \\ 34 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \\ 47 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

In other words, the first two numbers are known - 7 and 5 respectively. The third and the fourth numbers can be either 2 and 3, 1 and 4, or 0 and 5 respectively. Etc.

Another thing I know is the distribution of numbers.

N(0) = 1

N(1) = 2

N(2) = 3

N(3) = 1

N(4) = 1

N(5) = 4

N(6) = 3

N(7) = 1

In other words, I know there is only one zero, two ones, four fives, three sixes, etc.

Is there a mathematical apparatus, like a set of equations, that would allow me to analytically guess this 16-number array based on the knowledge I've listed above? And is it even possible to do this? Maybe, this puzzle has more than one solution?

For convenience, I'll add the answer: 7523066254112556

P.S. I have no idea what tags to add to this question, my apologies.

Comment: Analytically, step by step, this seems feasible. For example, $N(7)=1$ and $7$ is the first number in the array, so you can elimitate all other options of $7$ appearing anywhere in the array ($71,07,47$)... Then continue in the same manner until you are left with only one viable option (or several viable options if you know that this puzzle has more than one solution).

Comment: @barakmanos I doubt it is a way, because it will leave me with an array of possibilities where guesswork is inevitable.

Comment: Guesswork done in the right way is the same as backtrack, and it's one of the basic tools of solving combinatorial problems like this (or like Sudoku). Normally backtracking is better done by trying the less complex bifurcations first, so the system is quickly reduced to a simpler one.

Answer (score 1):

The most "theoretical" apparatus available for this kind of problem is the "dancing links" algorithm by Knuth.

This algorithm works for a specific kind of problems, called "exact cover", where you have a finite family of finite sets whose union is a set $S$, and you need to find a pairwise disjoint subfamily that still covers $S$.

Somehow you can think about the points as the "conditions" and the sets as the "choices". Every condition must be satisfied by exactly by one choice.

Many combinatorial problems can be transformed in an exact cover, like pentominoes, sudokus and many others. Beware that a cover for a simple 9x9 sudoku entails 324 points (like "in column $j$ digit $k$" or "cell $(m,n)$") and 729 subsets (representing the choice "put digit $k$ in cell $(i,j)$"). Each of the subsets/choices covers exactly 4 conditions (digit in row, column, block and "cell is filled") so problems seemingly grow when represented this way. But they are indeed simpler to solve as you can prove analytically that you can find all the solutions - no guesswork.

In your case, you start distinguishing the numbers that are equal, so you have this set of 16 "digits":
$$
0, 1_a, 1_b, 2_a, 2_b, 2_c, 3, 4, 5_a, 5_b, 5_c, 5_d, 6_a, 6_b, 6_c, 7
$$
to distribute in your 16 spaces, so you have 256 choices (subsets) named "put digit $x$ in space $y$". The only natural conditions (points) are that "in a space there must be exactly one digit" and "a digit can be used only once" (you can also add conditions so indices are always in the correct order, so digit $2_b$ in space $4$ will prevent digit $2_a$ in space $5$, but this will only help in finding a unique solution, which you can easily check by naked eye after all the solutions are found). Now add your initial choices (that is, keep only the available pairs), and the DLX algorithm will return all the solution in a fraction of a second, in a totally mechanical way.

Now, this is not very different to "guesswork", it's just formalized and optimized so no possible option is left behind.

So here it is what the DLX algorithm will do:

1. Seek the condition with the less choices satisfying it.

   - If there is no choice satisfying it, that there is no solution and you have to backtrack.
   - If there is only one choice satisfying it, then mark the choice and delete all the other intersecting choices (because only one choice should satisfy one condition)
   - If there is more than one choice, choose one, and go ahead. After the analysis of this choices, choose another, etc.
2. Once a choice is made, the problem is reduced to a smaller one, there are less conditions to satisfy, and less choices to make.

In your case, you start with (not expanding digits with their indices) - (option $33$ is removed because it's not compatible with having only one $3$):

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 23 \\ 14 \\ 05 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 06 \\ 15 \\ 24 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 71 \\ 62 \\ 53 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 54 \\ 63 \\ 72 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 07 \\ 16 \\ 25 \\ 34 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \\ 47 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The choice "in space $1$ there is one digit" is only satisfied by the choice "digit $7$ in space $1$" so you have to keep this choice, and remove al the incompatible ones, you are left with

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 23 \\ 14 \\ 05 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 06 \\ 15 \\ 24 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 62 \\ 53 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 54 \\ 63 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 16 \\ 25 \\ 34 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now you have to backtrack on point "digit on space 10" (only two possibilities - $3, 4$ - and a lot of reduction after each choice!).

1. for choice $3$ you get

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 14 \\ 05 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 06 \\ 15 \\ 24 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 62 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 63 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 16 \\ 25 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

which reduces again (all three $6$s are used) to

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 14 \\ 05 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 15 \\ 24 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 62 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 63 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 25 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

From here you trivially get two solutions:

$$
7514156263022556
$$
and
$$
7505246263112556
$$

2. For choice $4$ you get

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 23 \\ 05 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 06 \\ 15 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 62 \\ 53 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 54 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 16 \\ 25 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

You can rule out $(05)$ in the third and 4th space, because it will force $3$ in space 8 so another $5$ in space 7, totalling to five $5$s. So you set $(23)$ and remove the other $3$

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 75 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 23 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 06 \\ 15 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 62 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 54 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 02 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 16 \\ 25 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 56 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

and from here two more solutions can be found (just depending on the $1$s).
$$
7523066254112556
$$
and
$$
7523156254021656
$$